# Derivation of the Geodesic Equation from Hamilton-Jacobi Theory

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I'm trying to prove a result in my general relativity class and I'm confused. If we have the Hamiltonian:
$$ H = g^{\mu\nu}p_\mu p_\nu + m^2 $$
Subject to Hamilton's Equations:
$$\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \tau} =  N(\tau) \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_\mu}$$
and: 
$$\frac{\partial p_\mu}{\partial \tau} =  - N(\tau) \frac{\partial H}{\partial x^\mu}$$
Where $N(\tau)$ is just some function of $\tau$. I'm trying to prove that:
$$\frac{\partial^2 x^\mu}{\partial \tau^2} + \Gamma^\mu{}_{\alpha\beta} \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial \tau} = \text{(something)} \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \tau}$$
Such that the equation can be reparametrized so that (something) = 0 and we have the geodesic equation. What's primarily tripping me up is writing:
$$ \Gamma^\mu{}_{\alpha\beta} \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial \tau} $$ as proportional to $\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \tau}$ What I have so far is 
$$\Gamma^\mu{}_{\alpha\beta} \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial \tau} = \frac{N(\tau) p_\nu}{2}g^{\mu\gamma}\left(g_{\gamma\alpha,\beta} + g_{\beta\gamma, \alpha} - g_{\alpha\beta,\gamma} \right) g^{\alpha\nu} \frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial \tau}$$
So I guess my question is, is there a way to write:
$$ g^{\mu\gamma}\left(g_{\gamma\alpha,\beta} + g_{\beta\gamma, \alpha} - g_{\alpha\beta,\gamma} \right) g^{\alpha\nu} \frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial \tau}$$
Such that the indices $\beta$ and $\mu$ are switched, or such that this reduces in a nice way? Or have I been going about this problem incorrectly?